# VSC: color customization of error message

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

does somebody knows how to change color of this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awJKe.png)

i was messing around the color customization, i just overviewed settings end editor tokens but none of them was set to such a bright yellow color.

Comment: try the terminal colors of the theme

Comment: doesn't work, changing theme can't change settings.json as we can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `settings.json` change the `terminal.ansiYellow` for the theme you use.

In the example I used `Default Dark+` theme.

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      "terminal.ansiYellow": "#777117"
    }
  }
```

Maybe better to create an issue at the VSC repo to request a change of the bright Yellow of the `Default Dark+`

Or they should not use light colors on a light background, whatever the theme.